# Test billing products

Tags: android, in-app-billing, billing, android-billing

In the past we could test the in app purchase with static skus like following:

- android.test.purchased
- android.test.canceled
- android.test.refunded
- android.test.item_unavailable

This did work without the need of a published app.

Now (in billing v5) we can query products from the billing api. Is there a simple way to test the api without the app published? I could not find anything anymore... I'd simply want some static responses for products that are owned/not owned/not found...

I want to query products for those testing purposes only just to showcase the usage of a library of mine and I don't want to put this app to the play store just for this use case...